# PDF Hebrew convert issue

Tags: pdf, hebrew

When i convert, print or simple copy-paste pdf document in hebrew i get corrupted numbers. For example in output i get 4994-4999 instead of 1992-1999. Even LibreOffice open documents with this issue.

More examples (original -> output):

```
2008-2010 -> 9334-93.3‬
2011-2012 -> 4344-4344
321390445 -> 044093223
```

I tried this methods:

1. copy-paste
2. print document in another document
3. using LibreOffice and GoogleDrive to convert document
4. using command-line converters like pdf2txt, pdftotext, qpdf, pdftohtml

Comment: Most likely the PDF contains no information on which character a glyph represents, or even wrong information. If you share a sample file, we can check.

Comment: Document example with bug: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25681990/1992.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample document displays like this:

[image]

but copy&paste from Adobe Acrobat results in:

> 4144144714614 6991-6991

The reversal of the order of characters at first glance might have been accounted to the language of the text been set to Hebrew in the content stream:

```
/P <</MCID 0/Lang (he-IL)>> BDC
```

but that could not be the reason for multiple glyphs falsely extracted, e.g. both year numbers `1992` and `1996` are extracted as "6991".

The real culprit for this is in the **ToUnicode** table of the font used here:

```
2 beginbfchar
<0003> <0020>
<0010> <002D>
endbfchar
1 beginbfrange
<0014> <001A> [<0036> <0031> <0034> <0034> <0037> <0031> <0034>]
endbfrange
1 beginbfchar
<001C> <0039>
endbfchar
```

This table is used by text extractors to associate a glyph identifier with a Unicode code point. The bfchar and bfrange sections here imply this mapping:

```
0003 -> 0020 " "
0010 -> 002D "-"
0014 -> 0036 "6"
0015 -> 0031 "1"
0016 -> 0034 "4"
0017 -> 0034 "4"
0018 -> 0037 "7"
0019 -> 0031 "1"
001A -> 0034 "4"
001C -> 0039 "9"
```

Obviously three different glyphs are mapped to the digit "4" and two different ones to the digit "1".

Comparing the rendered glyphs with the glyph IDs in the text drawing operations, though,

```
[<0014001C001C0019>] TJ
[<0010>] TJ
[<0014001C001C0015>] TJ
[<0003>] TJ
[<00170019001A00170019001A001700180019001A>11<001400150016>] TJ
```

the table should have mapped like this:

```
0003 -> " "
0010 -> "-"
0014 -> "1"
0015 -> "2"
0016 -> "3"
0017 -> "4"
0018 -> "5"
0019 -> "6"
001A -> "7"
001C -> "9"
```

To me this looks like the tool which built the **ToUnicode** table was unaware either how glyphs are drawn in PDFs or how digits in clear text numbers are ordered.

The glyphs in the first string `<0014001C001C0019>` for the rightmost year `1996` are arranged left-to-right. If one assumed either the glyph order or the character order in the clear text to be right-to-left, though, one would come to the wrong conclusion that `0014` would map to "6" and `0019` to "1". Concluding wrongly like this for all strings from the text drawing operations quoted above and all glyph IDs not yet associated, one would get the wrong mapping as seen in the **ToUnicode** table in the PDF.

**Thus, in essence the PDF is lying about the which glyph represents which digit. To fix this, the producer program (or the tool generating the ToUnicode maps) has to be fixed.**

Comment: Its ms word generate documents like this.

Comment: Is there a way to translate this digits to normal in software parsers?

Comment: *Its ms word* - so it's an MS Word bug. *Is there a way to translate this digits to normal in software parsers* - as mentioned above, the **ToUnicode** maps essentially are trash here, at least for the digits. If inspecting MS Word generated PDF documents, one might find a rule how to fix the map. That would be a project in its own right, though.